# How can i raise activate event in Asp.net?Is there any possibility?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

We have activate event in windows application like that is there any event in asp.net? How can i raise activate like event in Asp.net?Is there any possibility?

Comment: It may help to explain further what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DOM events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/) and especially the [focus event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html), section "Focusing and blurring the entire window".

You need to write a Javascript handler for the required events which either updates the page via Ajax or raises an ASP.Net event.